# what kind of string does exist in a matlab vector?

Tags: matlab

I have a vector of strings like `mystr=['sa',ra,'sa','ba']`
How can I find which kind of strings do exist in my vector?
The answer for this simple example is: `'sa' 'ra' 'ba'`

Comment: `unique(mystr)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just find unique strings in cells

```
mystr={'sa','ra','sa','ba'} % [] results in concatenation
unique(mystr)
```